# Query return more data than will fit on a worksheet. I need to do VLOOKUP for 1 Column, but Merge (Left outer) and filtering 1 crash query

Tags: merge, multiple-columns, vlookup, branching-and-merging, ms-query

I need to do VLOOKUP adding several Columns with data from another file,
but once I do Merges (left outer) and load it - Im getting massage of more than 145M rows with proposal of converting into Data model.

When I press ok - its still not load anything...
Im new with Queries, perhaps standard Merge not help as what I've understood its merge entire data, but just display what you select.

Is there any way I can restrict\filter or another option how to add view Columns with VLOOKUP-ed data?

Thank you in advance!

I tried to Merge for each Column\data I need to add, but its not working.